# iCloud problem: "iCloud storage is full" message

Tags: icloud

I need help for this iCloud problem: I had no available space left, (of my 50GB plan) so, to keep using iCloud, I deleted some files. After that, instead fixing the problem, the system keep saying that "iCloud storage is full", or "there is no available space left on iCloud". I tried to deleted more files, also my iPhone backup of ~7GB, but iCloud seems not to detect I have done free space, and keep saying that there is no more storage. Has anyone had this issue? Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thank you and sorry for my English mistakes because it's not my first language.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iCloud storage full: "Not Enough Storage". Backups exceed 5GB](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193991/icloud-storage-full-not-enough-storage-backups-exceed-5gb)

Comment: I don't need to backup my phone, I just don't understand why it doesn't fix the size of the free space after I deleted some files.

Comment: Did you work through the answers in the question pointed to by @jimmy0x52?  Your problem might be a combination of things because it's obvious.  Be sure to try the solutions from other questions that are similar to yours.

Comment: I tried everything that post suggest but anything seems to work

Comment: you need to get the numbers for how much space you are using. You can usually get that by clicking on the manage button.

Answer (score 1):

Apple now has a web interface to view and manage (some of) your storage.

- https://www.icloud.com/#settings

I would go there and verify that the web interface matches the iOS device. If so, then you can go to the photo library and purge the Recently Deleted or work through the options given here:

- https://help.apple.com/icloud/#/mm93f1a9aac0

From your screen shot, you might need to download documents from iCloud Drive, but worst case, you will have followed the latest cleanup steps if you need to reach out to iCloud support to have them look at the code that checks free space and validate it against the lower numbers you are being shown on your Mac.

---

Apple also provides free support for accounts like AppleID and iCloud so you can get personalized help from:

- https://support.apple.com/

Comment: I'll try to contact the Apple support because anything seems to work

Comment: @G.Guidi That's fair - I'll add that to the answer.