# iCloud storage full but isn't

Tags: icloud, storage

So i have 50GB iCloud storage plan and it claims to be full. The main thing I use it for is Documents and Data. This accounts for 38GB. But when I checked it only stores like 2GB and my files are some of Pages files and some PDFs, my question is where is this 36GB of usage coming from?

[image: This is from manage storage]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of system preferences -> iCloud  -> manage? it can be media, or files on desktop(if allowed) etc.

Comment: i just updated it, take a look @ankii

Comment: Thanks @billy! I am very certain that this has been asked before. Just looking for  it.. See related questions first. also use appropriate tags. Sometimes things as simple as this work. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/202714/313842